# Backshift operator applied to a constant

Tags: time-series, self-study, autoregressive

This questions is two part:

1)  What happens when you apply the backshift operator to a constant?  For example, if I have the AR process
$$(1-\phi B)(y_t-\mu)=\epsilon_t$$
does that equal
$$y_t-\mu-\phi By_t-\phi B\mu = \epsilon_t$$
which (I believe reduces to)
$$y_t-\mu-\phi y_{t-1}-\phi \mu = \epsilon_t\longrightarrow y_t=\mu+\phi y_{t-1}+\phi \mu+\epsilon_t  $$

So am I correct in assuming that the backshift of a constant (in my example $\mu$) is just the constant?

2)  If I assume that $\epsilon_t\sim N(0,v)$, then what is the likelihood of the above AR process in 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Backshift operator operates normally on a constant as on every other symbol. So it shifts the constant one period back -where we find that the constant has the same value as in the current period, since this is what the essence of a constant is.

For the likelihood of an AR(1) process, in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72669/auto-regressive-process-maximum-likelihood-estimator/72719#72719) there is the likelihood for the case without the constant -but from there it is just a small step to here.

**ADDENDUM**
The chain rule will be the same, but the conditional density will be

$$Y_i | Y_{i-1},\dots,Y_0 \sim \mathcal{N}\left((1+\phi) \mu+\phi Y_{i-1},v\right) $$

You need to specify what the distribution of $Y_0$ will be (will it contain the unknown parameters  $\phi$, $v$? If not, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I am not sure I follow how to do this.  Do you think you could just show the last step of what the likelihood should be?