# Distribution fitting (maximum likelihood) for autocorrelated data

Tags: time-series, distributions, maximum-likelihood, arima, garch

I have some time series data that shows autocorrelation and seasonality. I want to fit a distribution to it. To use maximum likelihood it needs to be uncorrelated. I first fit a GARCH and an ARIMA model then use 
\begin{align}
\hat{y}_t=\frac{y_t-\mu_t}{\sigma_t}
\end{align}
as a filter to get rid of the correlation ($\sigma_t$ is from GARCH and $\mu_t$ is from ARIMA). Then I successfully fit a distribution to the transformed data $\hat{y}_t$ and obtain the CDF.

My question is how do I convert the result back to the original scale? i.e. how do I get the fitted CDF (of $y_t$) on the original scale?

Many thanks!

Comment: "To use maximum likelihood it needs to be uncorrelated": See this post http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72669/auto-regressive-process-maximum-likelihood-estimator/72719#72719