# Fit parametric distribution to time-series data

Tags: time-series, distributions, goodness-of-fit

I have a time-series of daily revenue data for a number of years and I would like to perform a parametric distribution fit to the data. Given that distribution fitting requires i.i.d. data, I presume I cannot use standard
methods. This is only for exploratory data analysis and verify some hypothesis on the form of the data. More specifically, a histogram of the data shows that the revenue is log-normally distributed and I would like to find the mean and standard deviation.

I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182232/fit-mixture-of-distributions-to-your-time-series-data-in-r) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84239/distribution-fitting-maximum-likelihood-for-autocorrelated-data) question but they did not seem to help me a lot.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?